# Unable to get Table Name using variable string MYSQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

```
 if ($_GET['category'] == "ebooks")
{ $tableName = $smallsubcodewithoutspace.'_ebooks';
  $sectionTitle = "Ebook";
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == "syllabus")
{ $tableName = $smallsubcodewithoutspace.'_syllabus';
  $sectionTitle = "Syllabus";
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == "pnotes")
{ $tableName = $smallsubcodewithoutspace.'_pnotes';
  $sectionTitle = "Practical Note";
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == "assignments")
{ $tableName = $smallsubcodewithoutspace.'_assignments';
  $sectionTitle = "Assignment";
}
elseif ($_GET['category'] == "tnotes")
{ $tableName = $smallsubcodewithoutspace.'_tnotes';
  $sectionTitle = "Theory Notes";
}

//if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validation
        if($contentTitle ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the Content Title !';
        }



        if($contentLink ==''){
            $error[] = "Please enter the Content Link !";
        }

        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tableName` (contentTitle,contentLink,contentAuthor) VALUES (:contentTitle, :contentLink, :contentAuthor)") ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':contentTitle' => $contentTitle,
                    ':contentLink' => $contentLink,
                                        ':contentAuthor' => $contentAuthor
                ));

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: add-content.php?notallowed=true');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<div align="center" class="alertpk"><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">'.$error.'</div></div>';
        }
    }
```

Actually, problem started when I tried inserting Table name with variable. Tables exist in database. total 5 databases are there in which I will insert data according to users  selection, but when form executed, a error is thrown saying:

> SQLstate[42000]: SYNTAX ERROR OR ACCESS VIOLATION 1103, INCORRECT TABLE NAME ' '

Answer (score 0):

The error `INCORRECT TABLE NAME ''` error means you don't have a value in `$tableName`.  Your `$_GET['category']` is not picking up a recognized value or the `extract($_POST)` is changing `$tableName` to an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I shifted tableVariables section inside try and its now working.

Answer (score -1):

var dump your variable, post to see what value comes up.